# Which is the most recommended sensor for sensing humans inside a rail passenger car?

Tags: sensor, detection

I am thinking of an application which is necessary to know if there is and where someone is located, inside a rail passenger car or bus, for example, the problem there is many external factors such as external sunlight or temperature that could disrupt thermal sensors, creating many false positives. In case of cameras some objects, like seats or other objects difficult to "see" people in a determined place. Another point is it is a real-time application, it means, the amount of generated date from cameras would be almost impossible for processing.

I am thinking to use ToF sensors or mm-Wave sensors, however, I do not know if the seats or some objects could difficult or even make impossible for sensing human.

Someone has some idea or advice which sensor could be used in such an application?

PS1: It is necessary to sense someone before he/she seats, I was thinking to set some ToF sensors on the ceiling of the wagon, in order to see when someone is passing through, however, I do not know if the same ToF can see someone while they are seating.

Comment: Not sure where you are based, but the new Thameslink trains in London have a sensing system like this. I remember seeing a job posting for R&D on this system some years ago (if memory serves me correctly, it was with City University Innovation Hub). A bit of googling might dig up some research details.

Comment: How quickly must your system determine yes-human, or no-just-heavy-package?

Comment: @analogsystemsrf, this system has to detect firstly someone while they are walking in the corridor, just after it has to see where each person is located. Therefore it is important to determine at the same time when someone is getting in.

Comment: Are you wanting to determine the presence of **any** humans, or are you specifically wanting to determine **how many**?

Comment: @ConcernedHobbit I want to determine the presence of any human, know how many are inside was just an idea to really know if someone is inside or not, considering that other sensors could not work due to false positives.

Answer (score 2):

Doppler RADAR can be used to provide an excellent person sensor, perhaps in conjunction with other secondary sensors. Doppler RADAR modules are available at low cost.

Secondary sensing could be by eg

PIR - motion detection.
IR - body heat
Ultrasonic  - motion detection
IR - beam breaking
Capacitive - body proximity.

**Doppler RADAR application:**

Person movement along a carriage can be detected by horizontal units and individual seats or areas by vertical units.

As well as whole body motion it is possible to detect physiological body attributes

- Knee joint articulation produces a frequency of about 25 Hz due to the action of the joint under load. I long ago met people who developed systems based on this feature. They claimed that it reliably detected people and rejected flapping curtains falling boxes and miscellaneous pussy cats.
- It should be possible to detect heart motion artefacts. This may require sensors located in seats. The cost of the RADAR units is low enough that a sensor per seat system may be economic.

---

The large range of low cost Doppler RADAR units appear to be based on the "RCWL-0516" module.

[**From here**](https://www.electroschematics.com/13246/get-started-microwave-radar-motion-sensor/):

[image]

- " ... The electronics of the module consists of two equally important sections: a microwave frequency transmitter/receiver/mixer based on the MMBR941M high-frequency NPN transistor and a much-lower-frequency section based on an IC — RCWL-9196. Technically, the microwave section resembles a “Colpitt oscillator,” with the requisite inductor (and capacitors) made by circuit board traces. The inductor (~10 nH) is the S curve trace on the top surface, and capacitors are the ring structure on the bottom surface and also the rectangular block to the left of the S curve. ..."

[Useful application article](https://www.electroschematics.com/13246/get-started-microwave-radar-motion-sensor/)
[and another](https://dronebotworkshop.com/rcwl-0516-experiments/)

[This Google search](https://www.google.com/search?q=RCWL-0516&oq=RCWL-0516&aqs=chrome..69i57j69i60l2j0l3.623j0j4&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8) provides many related links.

Many [**Ali Express Doppler RADAR units**](https://www.aliexpress.com/w/wholesale-radar-doppler.html)  - buyer beware as ever.

[Under $US1 each!](https://www.aliexpress.com/item/DC-12V-LV002-10-525GHz-8-15m-Doppler-Radar-Micro-wave-Microwave-Sensor-Switch-Module-DC/32910628243.html?spm=2114.search0104.3.40.72ac31d4hroeQQ&ws_ab_test=searchweb0_0,searchweb201602_5_10065_10068_10547_319_10059_10884_317_10548_10887_10696_321_322_10084_453_10083_454_10103_10618_10307_537_536,searchweb201603_52,ppcSwitch_0&algo_expid=618d6e9b-e052-4fe0-8791-44971b1788ff-6&algo_pvid=618d6e9b-e052-4fe0-8791-44971b1788ff)

[image]
Quality unknown.

Answer (score 1):

Thermal imaging cameras can be fed into image processing systems that can be programmed to discriminate ambient thermal signatures from those of humans, which are relatively consistent. All the camera system need do is find "blobs" of heat and count them. It's already being done all over the world.

[image: Thermal Image of Lounging Humans]

Comment: This is the same approach I was thinking of taking. In addition to using the thermal imaging, you could also incorporate image processing to eliminate false positives. E.g., only detect humans if it differs from an empty frame, only detect things at human body temperature, etc.

Comment: Just as a suggestion, the [FLIR Lepton](https://www.digikey.com/en/product-highlight/f/flir/lepton-lwir-camera-modules) is small, pretty inexpensive and meant for development. I've been playing around with one for a personal project

Comment: Thanks for the edit fixes...

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming the passengers must be sit down and will not travel stand.

My first though is using some sort of physical pressure sensor, that can detect if somebody is sit on a place.
However, this requires modifying the sits to add those sensors, maybe cutting the seat cloth.

I'm also thinking about ultrasonic sensor, that detect how far is an obstacle from the sensor. They can point to the sit from the roof, and if somebody is sit, it should detect a different distance than if the seat is empty.

However those sensors might not be very precise, and you can have weird situations that can give false positives, like if somebody puts some luggage on a seat.

Comment: Maybe temperature sensor (thermistor) in the seat will be cheaper and more accurate. I'm guessing the coaches are air conditioned, otherwise this level of accuracy may not be required. For non air conditioned general coaches (I'm in India), a footboard pressure sensor near entry/exit points may provide a reasonably good estimate of coach occupancy (although many people do tend to travel on the footboard itself).

Comment: @Indraneel I though about them too, but discarded because the sun might overheat a seat and cause easy false positives.

Comment: Yes, that can happen, although it might be possible to check with software (AI software which is the rage these days).

Comment: @DavidLor, thank you for your answer, however for my project, it is fundamental to sense someone while they are getting in the wagon and walking through the corridor, only after it is necessary to know where someone is located. the problem about using sensors in each seat is that all comunıcation will be via CANBUS, so each sensor needs an MCU to communicate using CAN protocol, so considering sensor + MCU in each seat in a whole train would increase a lot the cost, that's why I was thinking to use thermal sensor, it could give information of all persons in its range.